# Ошибка при удалении пользователя из БД

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой при работе с базой данных в SQLite.
В диалоговом окне я прошу ввести ID рабочего, чтобы потом его удалить. Код:

```
DeleteWorkerWindow dww = new DeleteWorkerWindow();
            if (dww.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                Worker SelectedWorker;
                using (AppContext db = new AppContext())
                {
                    SelectedWorker = db.Workers.FirstOrDefault(b => dww.WorkerID == b.WorkerID);
                }
                if (SelectedWorker != null)
                {
                    db.Workers.Remove(SelectedWorker);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Рабочий не найден");
                }
            }
```

в строке

```
db.Workers.Remove(SelectedWorker);
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."
```

Таблица в базе данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас два разных контекста БД используется. Один создаётся и уничтожается в блоке `using`. Другой существует независимо от него.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, в этом была ошибка, спасибо